Is it possible for allophonemes to be "conditional"?
What I mean by this, since I'm not sure if this even has a name, is if, say for example a language or dialect had allophony between something like /bʱ/ and /b/ in most words, but considered them different phonemes overall due to having words which could entirely change meaning depending on whether you pronounce, say, /b/ or /bʱ/, even if these only consisted of a small handful of words.
Also, what phonemes would be more or less likely for this kind of thing?

This is certainly a thing. A real-world example is Danish [a] and [ɑ], which are allophones of /a/, conditioned so that [a] appears in syllable coda and before alveolars, and [a] appears elsewhere – except in a small number of loan words where the quality follows the source language and even creates minimal pairs: expected ladte ‘loaded [pl.]’ with [a] due to the alveolar and hakker ‘is chopping’ with [ɑ] due to the velar, versus  (caffe) latte with [ɑ] despite the alveolar and hacker ‘hacker’ with [a] despite the velar. /ɑ/ is sometimes considered a marginal phoneme for this reason.

Correction to the above: [a] appears in syllable coda and before coronals, and [ɑ] appears elsewhere. Within Danish linguistics, it’s actually usually described the other way around: [ɑ] appears adjacent to labials and dorsals (including semivowels and /r/, which is pharyngeal/uvular), [a] elsewhere.

It's not unusual for contrasts between phonemes to be surpressed in certain phonotactic contexts.
An example of this in English would be that the phoneme pairs /p/ ~ /b/, /t/ ~ /d/, /k/ ~ /g/, and /kw/ ~ /gw/ do not contrast after /s/ (they are conventionally represented by the "voiceless" phoneme, as in the spelling, but phonetically are actually closer to the "voiced" phoneme).
This is typically phonologically conditioned however, whereas it sounds like you are suggesting an example where the contrast is instead lexically conditioned (i.e. present in certain words but not others, with no dependence on phonological context).
Situations in which two phones are not generally distinguished, except in limited circumstances, are generally referred to as "marginal phonemes".
It's quite common for marginal phonemes to occur only in onomatopoeias, ideophones, and loan words. I would expect that to be more relevant than the specific phoneme(s) in question.
That said, probably the most famous marginal phoneme I'm aware of is /ɫ(ˤ)/ in Arabic. It's not unusual for [ɫ(ˤ)] to occur as an allophone of /l/ when an emphatic (pharyngeal or pharyngealised) consonant appears nearby (either adjacent to it, or separated by a single vowel) but this sound does also occur in a single word (and derivatives of that word) where no such emphatic consonant appears: ﷲ‎ [ʔaɫ.ɫaːh] "Allāh, God"  (note that the glottal stop /ʔ/ and glottal fricative /h/ are not considered emphatic and do not trigger emphatic spreading).
As this phoneme occurs in a single word (and derivatives thereof) it is often omitted from Arabic phoneme inventories, and there are also no minimal pairs (meaning it fails to meet the strictest definitions of phonemicity). Nonetheless, pronunciations that use the typical unemphatic /l/ will be judged incorrect by most native speakers.

The [a ~ ɑ] distinction in Danish (see comments under question) does kind of show a case of lexical determination. Short /a/ is [ɑ] adjacent to labials and dorsals (+ onomatopoeia and some loan words), but there are also a few native words where word-initial [ɑ] appears before alveolar [n]: andre ‘other(s)’, vandre ‘wander’, the name Anders, etc. It’s assumed that this is due to distant assimilation from the /r/ in the following syllable, but in other comparable words (klandre ‘blame’, Sandra, Andreas, etc.), we find the expected [a], so it’s inconsistent and lexically determined.
